# Getting "unrecognized arguments" error when trying to exclude modules in PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to run pyinstaller inside of a python program.
Everything works except for when I try to use the `--exclude-module PIL` parameter, I get the following error:
`pyinstaller: error: unrecognized arguments: --exclude-module PIL`

Here's my exact code:

```
import PyInstaller.__main__

PyInstaller.__main__.run([
    'res/output/output.py',
    '--onedir',
    '--exclude-module PIL',
    "--noconsole"
])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split up the flags and its argument.

For Example:

```
PyInstaller.__main__.run([
    'res/output/output.py',
    '--onedir',
    '--exclude-module', 
    'PIL',
    '--noconsole'
])
```